# How to do parameterization in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, xml, junit, webdriver, testng

How to do parameterization in Selenium 2 (WebDriver)? I use Eclipse with maven plugins and I have no previous experience on Selenium Webdriver. When I google for it then every thing shows about testNG and JUnit. Is there any method through which we can parameterized the Webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make assumption - you would like to pass some parameter to the Webdriver. That can be done via two ways:

1. Make class which extends Webdriver and make its constructor to have the parameter which you need to pass. However, this is the **hard** way, because you have to implement/override all (needed) functions from webdriver:

   ```
   public class MyWebdriver extends Webdriver{
         private String theParameter;

        public MyWebdriver(String parameter){
          //... initialize the Webdriver

          //store the parameter
          theParameter = parameter
   }
   ```
2. Make your own wrapper, which will contain instance off WebDriver. That is **easy**(-ier). For example: In my own tests, I need to tell the Webdriver which environment I am testing. So I created my own class for the Environment:

   ```
   public class Environment{
     private String baseUrl;
     public enum NameOfEnvironment {DEV, ACC}
     private NameOfEnvironment environment;

     public Environment(NameOfEnvironment envName){
        environment = envName;
     }

     public String getBaseUrl(){
         switch (environment){
            case DEV: baseUrl = "https://10.10.11.12:9080/test/";
                      break;
            case ACC: baseUrl = "https://acceptance.our-official-site.com";
                      break;
         }
       return baseUrl;
     }
    }
   ```

and then I have my own WebDriver wrapper, where I initialize it like this:

```
public class TestUI{
      private Webdriver driver;
      private Environment env;

   public TestUI(Environment e){
       this.env = e;
       driver = new FirefoxDriver;
       driver.get(env.getBaseUrl());
   }
}
```

And in the test:

```
 public class TestCases{

   public static final Environment USED_ENVIRONMENT = new Environment(Environment.NameOfEnvironment.ACC);

 @Test
 public void testSomething(){
    testUI test = new testUI(USED_ENVIRONMENT);
    //.. further steps
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to try to use a testing framework (TestNG or Junit) which gives many more features than just parametrization.  Probably a little effort in setting up the framework in the beginning will save a lot of effort when your test code grows.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void property(){
    try {

        File file = new File("login.properties");
        FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(fileInput);
        fileInput.close();

        Enumeration enuKeys = properties.keys();
        while (enuKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) enuKeys.nextElement();
            String value = properties.getProperty(key);
            driver.findElement(By.id(key)).sendKeys(value);
            System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and to pass the values from the properties file use property(); in main class. and execute

Answer (score 0):

```
@Parameters({ "first-name" })
@Test
public void testSingleString(String firstName) {
  System.out.println("Invoked testString " + firstName);
  assert "Cedric".equals(firstName);
}
```

In this code, we specify that the parameter firstName of your Java method should receive the value of the XML parameter called first-name.  This XML parameter is defined in testng.xml:
    
      
      
      <-- ... -->

For more details, please visit the following:
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters

Comment: You can use either JUnit or TestNG as test framework. What do you want to use? I prefer TestNG. If you use TestNG, you need to make an XML file e.g. testng.xml where you can specify data to parameterize using @Parameters annotation of TestNG (which has been mentioned in above snippet of code

Answer (score 0):

Here i am providing a test case that might be helpful

```
 package pac1;
 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
  import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
 import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class test extends sut  {
static WebDriver driver;
static Wait<WebDriver> wait;
  public static boolean run(WebDriver driverArg, Wait<WebDriver> waitArg)
{
    driver = driverArg;
    wait = waitArg;
   // Run all the methods and return false if any fails
    return (test1() );
                  } 
   private static boolean test1()
   {



  driver.get("https://accounts.google.com");

    try {
        File file = new File("emaildata.xml"); //file location should be specified correctly put your xml in the same folder of the source code.
        // Prepare XML
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.parse(file);
        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList emailNodeElementList = document.getElementsByTagName("test");//test is the name of the child tag 
        for(int j=0;j<emailNodeElementList.getLength(); j++)//loop for the multiple data
    {
       String client = "The username or password you entered is incorrect. ?";
        Element emailNodeElement = (Element)emailNodeElementList.item(j);
        NodeList details = emailNodeElement.getChildNodes();
        String emailAddress=((Node) details.item(0)).getNodeValue();
        System.out.println("email :" + emailAddress);//it just prints which email is going to be parsed
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
            boolean feedBack = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).getText().contains(client);
            boolean feedbackVisible = element.isDisplayed();


    WebElement e1 = driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));//getting the location from the web
    e1.sendKeys(emailAddress);//sending keys to the server
    WebElement e3 = driver.findElement(By.id("signIn"));
    e3.click();


    if(feedBack==true){
        System.out.println(client+ "is present");
        if(feedbackVisible==true){
            System.out.println(client+ "is visible");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(client+ "is not visible");
        }

    }
    else{
        System.out.println(client+ "is not present");

    }
    }
  }
 catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

  return true;
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* You can pass parameters by creating two classes.
The first class, which you can call Main Class, will be public static void.
It will contain code such as:
*/
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
Parameters id = new Parameters();   //this is referring to second class
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(id.x);
//****************************************************************
//this is the second class [separate page] - here you can declare int or string varibale as public [so you can share them with other class while defining them]  - 
//when you make this class - don't need to add public static void

public String x = "username"
//if you look at the first page, I'm passing this string in the main script
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ReadExcel {
       public String readData (String strSheetName, int strRowNo, int strCellNo) throws Exception {

              FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:\\Selenium\\TestData.xlsx");
              Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
              Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(strSheetName);
              Row rw = sh.getRow(strRowNo);
              String val = rw.getCell(strCellNo).getStringCellValue();

              return val;

              }

}
```

Comment: String Username = read.readData("Sheet1", 1, 2);
  driver.findElement(By.id("ap_email")).sendKeys(Username);
  driver.findElement(By.id("continue")).click();
  
  String Password = read.readData("Sheet1", 1, 3);
  driver.findElement(By.id("ap_password")).sendKeys(Password);

Comment: Thanks for contribution to SO. Please take time and visit [SO Answering Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering). You should explain why you think this is a right answer